# DB2 SELECT which sums two columns and handles null values

Tags: select, db2, addition

Let's say I have flowing table MY_TABLE with columns A and B:

```
NULL, NULL
NULL, 1
1, NULL,
1, 1
0, 0
```

What I need is a select which returns:

```
NULL
1
1
2
0
```

```
SELECT A + B
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

will result in:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
2
0
```

Currently, I have written new MY_SUM function so I can have:

```
SELECT MY_SUM(A, B)
FROM MY_TABLE
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_SUM(IN decimalNumber1 DECIMAL(20, 2), IN decimalNumber2 DECIMAL(20, 2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(20, 2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE decimalSum DECIMAL(20, 2);

    IF decimalNumber1 IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET decimalSum = decimalNumber1;
    END IF;

    IF decimalNumber2 IS NOT NULL THEN 
        IF decimalSum IS NULL THEN
            SET decimalSum = decimalNumber2;
        ELSE
            SET decimalSum = decimalSum + decimalNumber2;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN decimalSum;
END
```

but I was wondering if there is a better out-of-the-box way for doing this?

Comment: To summarize your request you want NULL to be treated as 0 when there's one of them but stay NULL if there's two of them. They reason this doesn't exist out of the box is because that is not how NULL works.

Comment: Your comment really got me thinking. This really is an unusual situation because user must not input value when the value has not been provided. On the other hand, when time comes, we need to sum all available values.

SUM function for an example does something similar. It too ignores null values when summing through rows. Only difference is that sum is an agregate function that goes through rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`select case when a is null and b is null then null else coalesce(a,0)+coalesce(b,0) end from my_table`

or

`"select case when coalesce(a,b) is null then null else coalesce(a,0)+coalesce(b,0) end from my_table`

There are many other ways to do it.

Comment: So, there is no out of the box solution? The best I can do is write code more concise by using coalesce?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression works in your case:

```
COALESCE(A, B) - COALESCE(A, B) + COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0)
```

Comment: Just to clarify second one,
this part is taking care of "both null" cases: COALESCE(A, B) - COALESCE(A, B)
and this provides the sum value: COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0)

Comment: Correct. I’ve removed the 1-st expression to satisfy your updated example, where 0+0 must be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE will do the job - your problem is not fully described but check out this

```
WITH temp  (a, b) AS (
VALUES (NULL, NULL), (NULL, 1), (1, NULL), (1, 1)
)

SELECT COALESCE(a,0) + COALESCE(b,0)
FROM temp
WHERE COALESCE(a,0) + COALESCE(b,0) <> 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated the question with more examples to make it more clearer. Two NULLs must not be converted to a 0 or two zeroes to NULL. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: use a CASE to get what you need

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to transparently interpret `NULL`s as `0`s.

Probably the closest you can get is with a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_SUM(
    n1 DECFLOAT DEFAULT NAN
   ,n2 DECFLOAT DEFAULT NAN
   ,n3 DECFLOAT DEFAULT NAN
   ,n4 DECFLOAT DEFAULT NAN
   ,n5 DECFLOAT DEFAULT NAN
) RETURNS DECFLOAT
RETURN
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(NULLIF(n1,NAN),NULLIF(n2,NAN)) IS NOT NULL THEN
  + COALESCE(NULLIF(n1,NAN),0)
  + COALESCE(NULLIF(n2,NAN),0)
  + COALESCE(NULLIF(n3,NAN),0)
  + COALESCE(NULLIF(n4,NAN),0)
  + COALESCE(NULLIF(n5,NAN),0)
  END
```

which you can extend to support more columns as needed

```
SELECT MY_SUM(a,b) AS SUM
FROM TABLE(VALUES (NULL, NULL), (NULL, 1), (1, NULL), (1, 1)) T(a,b)
```

would then return

```
 S
 -

 1
 1
 2
```

Note The function could be simpler if you create one function for each number of parameters you want to sum, but the single function with `DEFAULT`s is neater